# Difference between `a ||= b` and `a = b if a.nil?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm inspecting a Rails project. On an ERuby HTML template page I saw a few lines like this:

```
<% option_1 = false if option_1.nil? %>
<% option_2 = false if option_2.nil? %>
<% option_3 = false if option_3.nil? %>
```

I can't understand why it isn't written like this:

```
<% option_1 ||= false %>
```

What's the difference of `||=` and `if nil?` in this case?

Comment: Why do `option_1` / `_2` / `_3` have to be `false` in the first place instead of just staying `nil`? Have you tried to remove those lines? I wouldn't be surprised if the code runs fine without it.

Comment: @Stefan Those lines ensure that the options exist. If they don't exist then subsequent `if`/`unless` tests are going to fail.

Comment: What do you mean by _"ensure that the options exist"_? There's no difference between `if false` and `if nil` ...

Comment: The two are equivalent , even if the variable (e.g., `option_1`) *has not been initialized!*

Comment: If I use a non-existent variable in `if foo ... end` then I get a `NameError`, but not when in `do_something if foo.nil?`, right?

Comment: _"If I use a non-existent variable ... I get a NameError"_ – yes, that's correct. But where do these local variables come from? Why are they not always defined? It seems to me as if the problem is being fixed on the wrong end.

Comment: @Stefan Because the template is referenced in another ERuby file like `<%= render 'category/page', option_2: value, option_4: value, option_7: value %>`, which makes all variables optional.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this particular case there's no difference, but it could be out of habit. Whenever I see `nil?` being used, it's almost always used inappropriately. In Ruby very few things are logically false, only literal `false` and `nil` are.

That means code like `if (!x.nil?)` is almost always better expressed as `if (x)` unless there's an expectation that `x` might be literal `false`.

I'd switch that to `||= false` because that has the same outcome, but it's largely a matter of preference. The only downside is that assignment will happen every time that line is run instead of once with the `.nil?` test.

Comment: So `a ||= b` runs when `a` is either `nil` or `false` instead of `nil`-only?

Comment: You got it. That's a subtle but sometimes important difference. In this particular case it doesn't seem to matter. If the assignment wasn't `false` but `super_expensive_method_call` which could under some circumstances return `false` then it'd be hugely different.

Comment: You mean the use of `a = b if a.nil?` is primarily a performance concern?

Comment: If sometimes in the code `b` is an expensive operation then it's perhaps done for consistency's sake. If that isn't the case this might be a pointless habit, or worse, [cargo cult programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming) where the reasons for doing it that way aren't understood but the tradition persists. Personally I think trailing `if` clauses are "surprise conditions" and should be avoided because they impair readability.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of defining the missing local variables, you can use [`local_assigns`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Template.html#method-i-local_assigns) in your views to reference local variables without causing a `NameError`.

So instead of:

```
<% option_1 ||= false %>
<% option_2 ||= false %>
<% option_3 ||= false %>

<% if option_1 %>
  ...
<% end %>

<% if option_2 %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

You have:

```
<% if local_assigns[:option_1] %>
  ...
<% end %>

<% if local_assigns[:option_2] %>
  ...
<% end %>
```